# How to make a string data type column as checkbox in Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I have a string field `IsEnabled`, it’s string. Value can be **Yes**, **No** or `null`. I am binding this column to grid column. It’s working as expected. But I want to show this on UI as checkbox. For value Yes, it should be checked or No or null it should be unchecked. And user can check/uncheck, based on user’s action. Yes or NO will be inserted in database.

I couldn’t find proper way of doing this, so what is the best way to handle this scenario?

I have tried by by adding one more bool field and setting it based on value Yes, No or null. And binding this field to grid.

But I am looking for a clean approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was looking for a Kendo MVC solution, So I have implemented it like the below.

Declare the property like this.

```
[UIHint("DropDownTemplate")]
public IsAllowedCls IsAllowed { get; set; }

public class IsAllowedCls
{
    public int IsAllowedKey { get; set; }
    public string IsAllowedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Add view under Views\Shared\EditorTemplates create the view named as DropDownTemplate with below content

```
@model FxTrader.Models.IsAllowedCls

    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("DropDownTemplate")
        .DataValueField("IsAllowedKey")
        .DataTextField("IsAllowedValue")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["IsAllowedData"])
    )
```

In the controller action method, add the below code.

```
ViewData["IsAllowedData"] = new List<IsAllowedCls>() { new IsAllowedCls { IsAllowedKey = 1, IsAllowedValue = "Yes" },
    new IsAllowedCls { IsAllowedKey = 0, IsAllowedValue = "No" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column template ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template)) to return a checkbox where the value is checked when the record's `IsEnabled` is *Yes*.

Then in the dataBound event of the grid ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound)) you would setup the event binding for the checkbox to get when the value changed.

Here is an example:

```js
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    {
        field: 'Name'
    },
    {
        field: 'name',
        template: function(dataItem) {
        var checkbox = $('<input />', {
          checked: dataItem.IsEnabled === 'Yes',
          type: 'checkbox'
        });
        return checkbox.prop('outerHTML');
      }
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    {
      Id: 1,
      Name: 'Person1',
      IsEnabled: 'Yes'
    },
    {
      Id: 2,
      Name: 'Person2',
      IsEnabled: 'No'
    },
    {
      Id: 3,
      Name: 'Person3',
      IsEnabled: 'No'
    }
  ],
  dataBound: function(e) {
    e.sender.table.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
      var checked = this.checked;
      // send your AJAX request
    });
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/igiTASAc